# Oracle SQL - How to add a filter on a case field that I created?

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle11g, casting

I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and have run into an issue where I'm trying to filter a report to only return records logged by a specific list of user names.

They are currently stored in the system in fields user.first_name and user.surname and I've created the following CAST field in the coding to join the two together:

```
CAST(USER.FIRST_NAME||' '||USER.SURNAME as VARCHAR (25)) as CUSTOMER
```

What I want to do now though is restrict it so that my query will only return records where the customer is in a pre-determined list that I can hard core into the SQL.
eg I only want to see records for :
Joe Bloggs,
John Doe,
A Nother

How do I do this in Oracle SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option (as you said you hardcoded it) is

```
select *
from your_table
where customer in ('Joe Bloggs', 'John Doe', 'A Nother');
```

A better one is to store those customers into a separate table and join it with your_table:

```
insert into separate_table (name) values ('Joe Bloggs'); -- do the same for the rest

select *
from your_table y join separate_table s on s.name = y.first_name ||' '||i.surname;
```

Even better, use their IDs (because, there could be two John Doe persons; which one will you take)?

```
insert into separate_table (id) values (1123); -- this is Joe Bloggs

select *
from your_table y join separate_table s on s.id = y.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I seem to be running into some errors when putting it in to my coding.

SELECT
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
   central_enquiry.enquiry_desc,
   central_enquiry.enquiry_time,
   user.title,
   user.firstname,
   user.surname
   
CAST(USER.FIRSTNAME||' '||USER.SURNAME as VARCHAR (25)) as CUSTOMER

FROM
   central_enquiry,
   user

WHERE
   user.enquiry_number = central_enquiry.enquiry_number

Comment: You're welcome. That query is invalid; misses a comma in front of CAST keyword. USER can't be a table name, it is a reserved word in Oracle. By the way, "some errors" is difficult to debug, you should specify those errors.

Comment: SELECT
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
   central_enquiry.enquiry_desc,
   central_enquiry.enquiry_time,
   enquiry_customer.customer_title,
   enquiry_customer.customer_forename,
   enquiry_customer.customer_name,
   
CAST(enquiry_customer.customer_forename||' '||enquiry_customer.customer_name as VARCHAR (25)) as CUSTOMER

FROM
   central_enquiry,
   enquiry_customer,
   enquiry_cust_link

WHERE
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_cust_link.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_cust_link.customer_number = enquiry_customer.customer_number

Comment: When I try and add the second lot of code I get the error message "The entered SQL is not valid.   SQLSTATE = S1000    [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended."

Comment: Well, the last SELECT statement you posted (as a comment) looks all right to me, there's nothing wrong with it (as far as I can tell). How do you run it? Why is ODBC involved? Possibly, see if terminating the statement with a semi-colon helps.

Comment: The statement I posted before the error message is what I've got working in SQL at the moment.
I'm not sure where to paste your code into the table.

insert into separate_table (name) values ('Joe Bloggs'); -- do the same for the rest

select *
from your_table y join separate_table s on s.name = y.first_name ||' '||i.surname;

I've tried

Comment: SELECT 
central_enquiry.enquiry_number, 
central_enquiry.enquiry_desc, 
central_enquiry.enquiry_time, 
enquiry_customer.customer_title, 
enquiry_customer.customer_forename, 
enquiry_customer.customer_name, 
CAST(enquiry_customer.customer_forename||' '||enquiry_customer.customer_name as VARCHAR (25)) as CUSTOMER 

insert into separate_table (name) values ('Joe Bloggs');
insert into separate_table (name) values ('John Doe');

select *
from enquiry_customer y join separate_table s on s.name = y.customer_forename||' '||y.customer_name;

Comment: FROM central_enquiry, 
enquiry_customer, 
enquiry_cust_link 

WHERE central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_cust_link.enquiry_number AND 
enquiry_cust_link.customer_number = enquiry_customer.customer_number